# How to convert a java linked list of a binary representation of a number to a String of the decimal representation of a number?

Tags: java, binary, iterator, type-conversion, decimal

I've built in java a new number type that holds a representation of a binary number as a link list of bits. The toString of my class prints the binary form of this number, but I want to create a function that prints the decimal representation of such number, and in order to work around the limitations of the number types, I want it to be in string form.
The problem is that i can't ever put the full number in an int or a long because my number type can hold a whole number of any size.
If someone needs to see the class or parts of it in order to help i can send it to them.

Comment: post the code here.

Comment: From what I could understand, you can use StringBuilder to concat your individual strings and then represent the decimal format for that  binary - Because you've mentioned you want it in a string form

Comment: There are classes BigInteger and BigDecimal for numbers of arbitrary size. These also include constructors that parse strings. Of course, the question is: why did you re-invent that wheel in the first place?

Comment: If you want to reinvent the wheel: Take any code for conversion from binary to decimal off the Internet. Implement it yourself using your own class.

Comment: @GhostCat an assignment dor my cs class

Answer (score 3):

Look into [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html). As your data structure allows for storing binary numbers of arbitrary size, BigInteger allows for storing integer numbers of arbitrary size.

As you are able to convert your list of bits to `String`, you might want to use this constructor [public BigInteger​(String val, int radix)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String,int)). For example, let's say an object `yourObject` of `YourClass` holds a list of bits 1 0 1 1 0, which prints out as "10110" using the `toString` method you have implemented. Now:

```java
YourClass yourObject; // 10110
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(yourObject.toString(), 2);
System.out.println(bi); // Prints out 22
```